# Match all numbers in regex except for phrase foo2020

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript, numbers

In a jumbled up string such as:
dfnjvqifoo2020o43e25w54p32n5qvto4325432543nvgn4325gn2020repw

I want to match all numbers from the string except the phrase foo2020

I have tried /(?<!foo)\d+/g
The problem is that the 020 in foo2020 gets matched when it's not supposed to, I know it's because \d means matching a single digit but I don't know how to get around this

Comment: You could use an alternation with a capturing group `foo\d+|(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/oKC0SP/1 The digits that you are looking for are in group 1.

Comment: Also to help clarify, the 2020 shouldn't get matched because it's followed by 'foo'

Comment: You can match what you don't want (which is `foo2020`), then capture in a group what you do want. `foo\d+|(\d+)`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to regex, whats an alteration? I can see in the example foo2020 is highlighted a different color.

Comment: The alternation `|` means `OR` What you don't want is highlighted in blue, the captured group is highlighted in green.

Comment: Another option is using `(?<!foo\d*)\d+` https://regex101.com/r/nYkR4S/1

Comment: Omg thank you so much, this has given me such a headache for hours

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer that works best for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex, `/(?<!foo)\d+/g`, matches any one or more digits that are *not immediately* preceded with `foo`. That means, if a *leftmost* digit is not *immediately* preceded with `foo`, it will be matched with this regex.

All you need to do is add another restriction: *do not start matching digits if there is a digit immediately on the left*, i.e. add `(?<!\d)`, a **left-hand digit boundary construct**.

```
/(?<!foo)(?<!\d)\d+/g
//       ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/97oOpq/1).

Note the two consecutive lookbehinds, `(?<!foo)(?<!\d)` are executed at the same position one after another, which means there will be no match if there is `foo` ***or*** a digit immediately to the left of the current location.

If you need to make sure there is no digit *immediately on the right*, append `(?!\d)`, a **right-hand digit boundary construct**, after `\d+` pattern. It is not required here, but if you  need to match `50` in `abc50def` and not in `abc500def`, you would need this negative lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the match only, you could add `\d*` to the lookbehind. Note that this is not widely supported by all browsers. I will work in for example chrome or nodejs.

```
(?<!foo\d*)\d+
```

*Explanation*

- `(?<!foo\d*)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not `foo` followed by 0+ digits
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nYkR4S/1)

---

Another option is to use a capturing group, match what you don't want and capture what you do want.

```
foo\d+|(\d+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oKC0SP/1)

Comment: 7 browsers out of 17 [listed here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) do not support lookbehind. So, the ~59% browsers already support lookbehind (FireFox [will support lookbehind](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/78) in 3 days, thus, counting it in)